# Elegant Proof of $\frac{2}{5}\left(\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{x}\right)+\frac{14}{5}\frac{3\sqrt[3]{xyz}}{x+y+z}\geq4$

Tags: inequality

I've been looking at the inequality: for $x, y, z > 0$,
$$\left(1-\frac{3}{5}\right)\left(\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{x}\right)+\left(1+3\cdot\frac{3}{5}\right)\frac{3\sqrt[3]{xyz}}{x+y+z}\geq4$$
Which proved to be surprisingly resistant to more 'elegant methods' or I'm just oblivious to something obvious.
Buffalo way works after clearing the cubic root via $x=a^3$, $y=b^3$, $z=c^3$ and clearing the denominators:
$$\left(1-\frac{3}{5}\right)\left(a^{6}b^{6}+b^{6}c^{6}+c^{6}a^{6}+a^{3}b^{9}+b^{3}c^{9}+c^{3}a^{9}\right)+\left(3+9\frac{3}{5}\right)a^{4}b^{4}c^{4}\geq\left(3+\frac{3}{5}\right)a^{3}b^{3}c^{3}\left(a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}\right)$$
, then we need to check 2 cases as there's only cyclic symmetry.

Case 1. $a\leq b\leq c$, set $b=a+u$ and $c=a+u+v$ and expand:
$$
 \begin{array}{c}
  2u^{3}(u+v)^{6}(2u+v)\left(u^{2}+uv+v^{2}\right)+\\
  6au^{2}(u+v)^{5}\left(8u^{4}+15u^{3}v+15u^{2}v^{2}+7uv^{3}+v^{4}\right)+\\
  6a^{2}u(u+v)^{4}\left(44u^{5}+99u^{4}v+105u^{3}v^{2}+58u^{2}v^{3}+14uv^{4}+v^{5}\right)+\\
  2a^{3}\left(423u^{9}+2394u^{8}v+5958u^{7}v^{2}+8547u^{6}v^{3}+7761u^{5}v^{4}+4566u^{4}v^{5}+1691u^{3}v^{6}+360u^{2}v^{7}+36uv^{8}+v^{9}\right)+\\
  6a^{4}\left(286u^{8}+1462u^{7}v+3234u^{6}v^{2}+4018u^{5}v^{3}+3072u^{4}v^{4}+1468u^{3}v^{5}+416u^{2}v^{6}+60uv^{7}+3v^{8}\right)+\\
  6a^{5}(2u+v)\left(190u^{6}+780u^{5}v+1311u^{4}v^{2}+1126u^{3}v^{3}+542u^{2}v^{4}+137uv^{5}+12v^{6}\right)+\\
  2a^{6}\left(1001u^{6}+4137u^{5}v+6918u^{4}v^{2}+5807u^{3}v^{3}+2739u^{2}v^{4}+714uv^{5}+77v^{6}\right)+\\
  6a^{7}\left(192u^{5}+705u^{4}v+974u^{3}v^{2}+594u^{2}v^{3}+189uv^{4}+28v^{5}\right)+\\
  6a^{8}\left(71u^{4}+223u^{3}v+237u^{2}v^{2}+85uv^{3}+14v^{4}\right)+\\
  2a^{9}\left(49u^{3}+114u^{2}v+87uv^{2}+11v^{3}\right)+\\
  12a^{10}\left(u^{2}+uv+v^{2}\right)
 \end{array}
 $$
All coefficients are non-negative, we're done with this case.

Case 2.  $a\leq c\leq b$,  $b=a+u+v$ and $c=a+u$ and expand:
$$
 \begin{array}{c}
  2u^{6}(u+v)^{3}(2u+v)\left(u^{2}+uv+v^{2}\right)+\\
  6au^{5}(u+v)^{2}\left(8u^{4}+17u^{3}v+18u^{2}v^{2}+10uv^{3}+2v^{4}\right)+\\
  6a^{2}u^{4}(u+v)\left(44u^{5}+121u^{4}v+149u^{3}v^{2}+103u^{2}v^{3}+37uv^{4}+5v^{5}\right)+\\
  2a^{3}\left(423u^{9}+1413u^{8}v+2034u^{7}v^{2}+1659u^{6}v^{3}+831u^{5}v^{4}+282u^{4}v^{5}+95u^{3}v^{6}+36u^{2}v^{7}+9uv^{8}+v^{9}\right)+\\
  6a^{4}\left(286u^{8}+826u^{7}v+1008u^{6}v^{2}+700u^{5}v^{3}+342u^{4}v^{4}+166u^{3}v^{5}+80u^{2}v^{6}+24uv^{7}+3v^{8}\right)+\\
  6a^{5}(2u+v)\left(190u^{6}+360u^{5}v+261u^{4}v^{2}+118u^{3}v^{3}+80u^{2}v^{4}+53uv^{5}+12v^{6}\right)+\\
  2a^{6}\left(1001u^{6}+1869u^{5}v+1248u^{4}v^{2}+515u^{3}v^{3}+471u^{2}v^{4}+336uv^{5}+77v^{6}\right)+\\
  6a^{7}\left(192u^{5}+255u^{4}v+74u^{3}v^{2}+18u^{2}v^{3}+63uv^{4}+28v^{5}\right)+\\
  6a^{8}\left(71u^{4}+61u^{3}v-6u^{2}v^{2}+4uv^{3}+14v^{4}\right)+\\
  2a^{9}\left(49u^{3}+33u^{2}v+6uv^{2}+11v^{3}\right)+\\
  12a^{10}\left(u^{2}+uv+v^{2}\right)
 \end{array}
 $$
We need to verify:
$71u^{4}+61u^{3}v-6u^{2}v^{2}+4uv^{3}+14v^{4}=71u^{4}+52u^{3}v+6u^{2}v^{2}+14v^{4}+\left(3u-2v\right)^{2}uv\geq0$ so we're done

Other way to go is showing with CAS that:
$$
 \frac{x^{3}z+x^{2}y^{2}-3x^{2}yz+x^{2}z^{2}+xy^{3}-3xy^{2}z-3xyz^{2}+3xyz\sqrt[3]{xyz}+y^{2}z^{2}+yz^{3}}{x^{3}z+x^{2}y^{2}+x^{2}yz+x^{2}z^{2}+xy^{3}+xy^{2}z+xyz^{2}-9xyz\sqrt[3]{xyz}+y^{2}z^{2}+yz^{3}}\geq\frac{3}{5}
 $$
Which also gets us that the inequality holds and even strengthens the result somewhat (around ~0.65). Can anyone suggest a solution with less legwork?

Comment: Replacing $\frac{3}{5}$ with any constant larger than $\frac{1}{16}$ would be welcome, too, for $\frac{1}{16}$ and below weighted AM-GM works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some thoughts.**

Hope it helps.

**Approach 1.**

We have
$$\frac{3\sqrt[3]{xyz}}{x + y + z} = \frac{3xyz}{3\sqrt[3]{xyz \cdot xyz \cdot \frac{(x+y+z)^3}{27}}}
\ge \frac{3xyz}{xyz + xyz + \frac{(x+y+z)^3}{27}}.
$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\left(1-\frac{3}{5}\right)\left(\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{x}\right)+\left(1+3\cdot\frac{3}{5}\right)\frac{3xyz}{xyz + xyz + \frac{(x+y+z)^3}{27}}\geq 4.$$

**Approach 2.**

WLOG, assume that $xyz = 1$.

We use the pqr method.

Let $p = x + y + z, q = xy + yz + zx, r = xyz = 1$.

We have
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{x} \\
 ={}& \frac{xy^2 + yz^2 + zx^2}{xyz}\\
 ={}& xy^2 + yz^2 + zx^2 \\
 ={}& \frac{xy^2 + yz^2 + zx^2 + (x^2y + y^2z + z^2x)}{2} + \frac{xy^2 + yz^2 + zx^2 - (x^2y + y^2z + z^2x)}{2}\\
 ={}& \frac{xy^2 + yz^2 + zx^2 + (x^2y + y^2z + z^2x)}{2} + \frac12(x - y)(y - z)(z - x)\\
 \ge{}& \frac{xy^2 + yz^2 + zx^2 + (x^2y + y^2z + z^2x)}{2} - \frac12\sqrt{(x - y)^2(y - z)^2(z - x)^2}\\
 ={}& \frac{pq - 3}{2} - \frac12\sqrt{p^2q^2 - 4p^3 - 4q^3 + 18pq - 27}.
\end{align*}

It suffices to prove that
$$\left(1-\frac{3}{5}\right)\left(\frac{pq - 3}{2} - \frac12\sqrt{p^2q^2 - 4p^3 - 4q^3 + 18pq - 27}\right)+\left(1+3\cdot\frac{3}{5}\right)
\frac{3}{p}\ge 4$$
or
$$p^2q - 23p + 42 \ge p \sqrt{p^2q^2 - 4p^3 - 4q^3 + 18pq - 27}.$$

We can prove that $p^2q - 23p + 42 \ge 0$.

It suffices to prove that
$$(p^2q - 23p + 42)^2 \ge p^2 (p^2q^2 - 4p^3 - 4q^3 + 18pq - 27)$$
or
$$ p(p^2 - 4pq + 16p - 21)^2 + (7p^3 + 10p^2 - 217p + 392)(p- 3)^2 + 8p^2q(p - q)^2 \ge 0 $$
which is clearly true (*note*: $7p^3 + 10p^2 - 217p + 392 > 0$).

Comment: thanks, that's much more manageable, just what I was after

Comment: @asomog Honestly, my proof is not nice.